# EventListener Performed by case

Tags: java, swing

I would like to know the best way to approach what I am trying to achieve, I can't figure out the logical path I should take.

I have a JTextField and a JTextButton, when input is added to the JTextField and either enter or the button is pressed, it will display on the JTextArea. Now, what I want is to choose when and what the JTextArea and Button do.

For example I want default Enter & Button to display next append text in my code. Then when a case is presented I want the JTextField to only accept either int or string and then once completed, I want it to go back to default.

I don't know if what I am trying to do is logical or best practice...

The idea behind this is, I have a story text based gui game. I want it to display text to the JTextArea and when Enter or button is pressed to display the next line of text and when in the story it requires user input, the JTextArea will look for that input.

So far I have an EventListener and ActionListener which submits what I type from JTextField to JTextArea, but that is about it.

Comment: You could just make a function to validate the input of your textfield. Make a class or Enum called UseCase or something, containing your constellations, and switch it around as needed. I see what you're trying to do and it's definitely not the worst practice. I WAS going to suggest JFormattedTextField as well, but I don't have any experience with that besides bad things I read on the internet.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7ZWsMAVw <- maybe this helps

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am still new to Java (about six months). I made this game as my first project using only console and completed it, and decided I wanted to take my study to the next level and make it GUI. 

Are you able to provide me with an example or if you have any links to guide me what you said? I get what you said but I am not knowledge enough to be able to produce what you said.

Comment: The pastebin link I added is a "should be working" code example of what I said, try to mess around with it so it suits your needs. It's probably not ideal, but it should be workable.

Comment: Oh! Thanks very much :D I shall have a play around with this and report my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your assistance! I have solved my issue, not sure if this is the "Best Solution". I combined your solution with a bit of tweaking.

In this instance, buttonState is an int which can be changed throughout my code by calling a constructor "setButtonState". I could have made buttonState a static to make things easier, but thought I could keep things clean.

```
 enterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {   //This is used so when the enter screen button is pressed, it will submit text from text field to text area.

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = inputTextField.getText();
                InputTextFieldEvent event = new InputTextFieldEvent(this, text);

                if (buttonState == 0) //Displays all text in JTextField to JTextArea, mostly for testing purposes.
                {
                    if (textInputListener != null) {
                        textInputListener.setInputListenerOccurred(event);
                    }
                }
                if (buttonState == 1) //Only accepts string for answer
                {
                    if (inputTextField.getText().matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
                    {
                        textInputListener.setInputListenerOccurred(event);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        getAppendMainTextArea("You have entered an invalid input, only letters are allowed.");
                    }
                }
                if (buttonState == 2) //Only accepts int for answer
                {
                    if (inputTextField.getText().matches("[0-9]+"))
                    {
                        textInputListener.setInputListenerOccurred(event);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        getAppendMainTextArea("You have entered an invalid input, only numbers are allowed.");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```